# Real-time page updating on server using an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, ejs

I have a javascript client application and express.js server.

I want to update a page in my server with some information that i'm sending with an ajax call from my client application, and i need the page to be updated real time.

In my javascript:

```
var url = 'http://'+base_url+'/make-order';

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data : {data : JSON.stringify(info)}

    }).done(function(res){
       //finished
    });
```

In my express router:

```
mobile_router.post('/make-order', function(req, res){
    // here i need to update some page in the server without rendering it
    // back to the client, res.end('updated') is enough 
});
```

Comment: You'd better use websocket.the way you approach is called comet though,it's kind of old school and have disadvantage points compared with websocket.

Comment: Your question doesn't describe the problem you're experiencing with your code. Help us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developing real-time application with node.js, you can use [socket.io](http://socket.io/).
Sample code from socket.io website: http://socket.io/docs/

Server (app.js)

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Client (index.html)

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: With a bit changes, socket.io got the job done perfectly, my explanation wasn't accurate but i got the direction from your answer